# Doing a three table join in MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is my table

```
program_join ('program_join_id, member_ID, program_schedule_id');

program_schedule (program_scedule_id, program_id, datetime');

program ('program_id, program_name);
```

This is my mysql

```
$mySql = "SELECT 
            program_join.program_join_id,
            member.member_username, 
            program_join.program_schedule_id

            FROM program_join

                INNER JOIN member ON
                program_join.member_ID=member.member_ID
                ORDER BY program_join_id";


$myQry = mysql_query($mySql, $DB)  or die ("wrong query : ".mysql_error());
$number = $hal; 
while ($myData = mysql_fetch_row($myQry)) {
    $number++;
    $code = $myData[0];
?>
<tr align="center">
    <td><?php echo $number;?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $myData[1];?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $myData[2];?></td>
```

result

```
No      username      program schedule
1        lalala          1
2        bababba         2
```

and under the 'program schedule', i want to show the program name that i have from the ' program_join.program_schedule_id'

please help me

Comment: So what's the problem? You already know how to do a `join`, since you have one in your query already.

Comment: i want to show the program name under the program schedule instead of the ID

Comment: so join in the table that contains that information... using the exact same type of join you've already used.

Comment: i have already join the table, it says wrong query.

Comment: Due to `LIMIT $hal, $line` [your query is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886670/sql-injection-and-the-limit-clause#29612558).

Comment: nope, thats my pagination

Comment: @lalala Nope, that's a probable SQL injection hole.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @lalala Please do not vandalize your posts or the posts of others. If you try to revandalize a post that has been fixed, a moderator will be informed. The moderator will roll back your vandalism, and hand you a suspension which will prevent you from further editing. **Attempts at vandalism are ultimately futile.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use joins to get the program_name from the program table:

```
SELECT 
pj.program_join_id,
m.member_username, 
p.program_name,
ps.datetime

FROM program_join pj
INNER JOIN member m ON pj.member_ID=m.member_ID
INNER JOIN program_schedule ps ON ps.program_schedule_id = pj.program_schedule_id
INNER JOIN program p ON p.program_id = ps.program_id
ORDER BY ... blah blah
```

Comment: hi can you check for me.  <td width="44" align="center"><a href="?editprofile.php&code=<?php echo $code; ?>" target="_self" alt="Edit Data">Edit</a></td>  is this the correct format?

Comment: @lalala - I'm not sure what you're asking.  That doesn't appear to be related to MySQL.

Comment: // copy file
  if (trim($_FILES['Filename']['name']) =="") {
   $file_name = $_POST['txtFilename'];
  }
  else {
   // If the old image file exists, will be deleted
   if(file_exists("images1/classes/".$_POST['txtFilename'])) {
    unlink("images1/classes/".$_POST['txtFilename']); 
   }
   
   //new image file (added)
   $file_name = $_FILES['Filename']['name'];
   $file_name = stripslashes($file_name);
   $file_name = str_replace("'","",$file_name);

   $file_name = $code.".".$file_name;
   copy($_FILES['Filename']['tmp_name'],"images1/classes/$file_name.jpg");
  }

Comment: for updating image, but it doesnt work, can you help me?

Comment: @lalala - your best bet is to open a new question so you can give an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is one more table named `program_schedule`, I would add one more join and get the required column, below is the example query (with assumed table/column names):

```
SELECT 
            program_join.program_join_id,
            member.member_username, 
            program_join.program_schedule_id,
            program_schedule.program_name

            FROM program_join

                INNER JOIN member ON
                program_join.member_ID=member.member_ID
                JOIN program_schedule on program_schedule.id = program_join.program_schedule_id,
                ORDER BY program_join_id ASC LIMIT $hal, $line";
```

Comment: but i dont have program_name in me program_schedule